# How to Send Text Message to Android and Start Application or Application Activity

Tags: android, gps, java-web-start

My question is very simple and I know the function can be preformed. I want to start activity via text message like "WHERE IS MY DROID" how can this be done? Please provide any information. I think SMSReceiver BroadcastReceiver is in the correct direction but I am not sure.

Comment: You have to create a listener on a text message receiving.
See that : http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register an Broadcast Receiver in AndroidManifest.xml for Receiving SMS_RECIVERD Broadcast as:

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add permission  in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

in your Broadcast Receiver code start your Application as:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){      
   //context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));

   //Start activity as:
    Intent intent24 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(
    Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER).setClassName("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
    "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME..YOURACTIVITY_NAME").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND).setComponent(new ComponentName("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME",
    "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME..YOURACTIVITY_NAME"));
    context.startActivity(intent24);
   }
 }
}
```

**NOTE :** For starting your Activity from background you need to set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND` flags in intent for starting activity from background.

Comment: I am trying your code but How do I set the Key Word to start the activity?

Comment: sorry i think you want read message when received on device and read message text if it is "WHERE IS MY DROID" then you want to start your activity right
?

Comment: solved or not? if not then tell me i will help you more on this problem.thanks\

Comment: Yes this Solved the problem, but I don't want the activity to start on every text message ...

Comment: ok then can you edit your post with SMSReceiver BroadcastReceiver code then i will edit code help more.thnaks

Comment: I got the application work per your code like a charm, but I still have the problem of the keyword. I can use numbers with no problem, even 1 number but I cant cross over to alphabet. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this guy's sample code for intercepting SMS's http://imran-android-sms.blogspot.com/2011/03/receive-sms-on-android.html#more

From there you just want to fire off an intent to whatever your new activity should be.